# What is required to 'upgrade' software from DAL C to DAL A?

Tags: avionics, software

What are the things to be noted or considered if a software which was initially treated as DAL C and later wanted to be considered as DAL A?

Comment: Read DO-178C and look for the different requirements between level A and C.

Comment: This question is understood by software developers familiar with certification requirements.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference in effort is in the amount of verification required.

Design Assurance Level (DAL) C only requires statement coverage whereas DAL A requires MC/DC coverage.

Some of the DO-178C objectives have to be meet with independence where they didn't need to be previously, and some life cycle data goes from CC2 to CC1.

I would suggest looking at the objective tables A1-A10 in DO-178C